# uicollectionviewcell doesn't get selected

Tags: xcode, events, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My app is based on a navigation controller that contains a a custom view controller which embed two view controllers.
The first one is an UICollectionViewController for which I have designed the cell via IB.
Cell contains an imageview and a label.
On the execution the app shows correctly all the cells with their images and related labels, but only some of them trigger the DidSelect event when you touch them.
I have tried to change the cell position on the screen changing the interspace setting within IB, and in this way some of the cells that before were "insensitive" now are sensitive and vice versa.
I have also checked that both image and label are user interactive.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple mistake: in the container view I inserted two views, the view containing the UICollectionViewController is below the other, whose content, most of the time, is hidden, but I set hidden the view contained not this specific one.